# Magento 2: Get product price from id? or sku?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, price

Is there anyway I can display the price of a certain product by id or sku?

something like this piece of code:

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

But I need to be able to put a sku or id somewhere in that code to display a price of a product on another page.

*I need to be able to do it on a cms page

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it's not working.

Comment: You can upvote and accept answer if it's helpful for you. So, other user can use this code.

Comment: It's not working on an cms page @RohanHapani

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` class to get price of product

**=> Factory Method :**

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
    ...      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ...
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

public function getPriceById($id)
{
    //$id = '21'; //Product ID
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $productPriceById = $product->load($id)->getPrice();
    return $productPriceById;
}

public function getPriceBySku($sku)
{   
    //$sku = 'testing'; //Product sku
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $productPriceBySku = $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)->getPrice();
    return $productPriceBySku;
}
```

**=> Object Manager Method :**

*BY Id :*

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(your-product-id);
$productPriceById = $productCollection->getPrice();
```

*By Sku :*

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', your-sku);
$productPriceBySku = $productCollection->getPrice();
```

Comment: Anyway to do it on an cms page?

Comment: You can do it by object manager. But, it's not proper way.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Hi but when I put that into an cms page the front end just shows me the code.

Comment: Add from admin side cms page or from using file?

Comment: How to get special price, I need to show price with RRP as well as net price

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try below code

```
<?php

    $productId = 8 //product id

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $productRepository  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $product = $productRepository->getById($productId);


    $abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');     
    echo $price =$abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product);


?>
```

Comment: Anyway of doing it on an cms page?

Comment: yes you can, add template in cms page and add code in template